# Returning inclass structure

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a template class with the following structure

```
//CFoo.hpp (header file)
template <typename T>
class CFoo {
        struct SFoo {
            T *ptr;
            /* rest is irrelevant */
        } *foo;

    public:
    /* omitting irrelevant parts */
    SFoo* get();
};
```

Now, if I implement the method **SFoo* get()** inside header file everything works nice. However, if I separate declaration and definition my code stops working with the followingg compilation errors.

```
//CFoo.cpp (source code, example 1)
/* omitting irrelevant parts */
template <typename T>
SFoo* CFoo<T>::get() { return foo; } //ERROR HERE
```

Error: `<where-is-the-error>: error: ‘SFoo’ does not name a type`

```
//CFoo.cpp (source code, example 2)
/* omitting irrelevant parts */
template <typename T>
CFoo<T>::SFoo* CFoo<T>::get() { return foo; } //ERROR HERE
```

Error: `<where-is-the-error>: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘CFoo<T>::SFoo’ because ‘CFoo<T>’ is a dependent scope`

I'm looking forward to any hints on how to fix that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to put in `typename` as the last error suggests?

Comment: @Timbo Where to put this keyword? I suppose I got it just right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to qualify dependent types using `typename`.  See [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

```
//CFoo.cpp (source code, example 2)
/* omitting irrelevant parts */
template <typename T>
typename CFoo<T>::SFoo* CFoo<T>::get() { return foo; }
^^^^^^^^
```

In C++11 you can use `auto` instead since `SFoo` will be in scope after the function name

```
template <typename T>
auto CFoo<T>::get() -> SFoo* { return foo; }
```

Comment: Now all C++ needs to do is replace `auto` by the keywords `function` and `var` and we have us a decent language going. `var x = 1;` … `function foo() -> int { return 42; }`

Answer (score 1):

You need to fully qualify `SFoo` when outside of the class declaration: `typename CFoo<T>::SFoo`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, `typename` has to be used whenever a name that depends on a template parameter is a type.

```
template <typename T>
typename CFoo<T>::SFoo* CFoo<T>::get() { return foo; }
```

**§ 14.6.2 Name resolution**

> A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is
>   dependent on a template-parameter is assumed not to name a type unless
>   the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified
>   by the keyword typename.